# Целочисленное деление (//) в Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, деление

Поясните, пожалуйста, как работает целочисленное деление в Python 3. Мне не понятен один конкретный пример:

```
print(4//3)
print(-4//3)
```

По моей логике, результатами обоих выражений должно быть число (±) 1. Но если в первом примере мои предположения оправдываются, то во втором - нет. Откуда я взял, что результат именно (±) 1? Потому, что ответами без округления будут:
1,3333333...
-1,333333...
соответственно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Целочисленное деление отбрасывает дробную часть, приводя ближайшее МЕНЬШЕЕ целое число. Если в случае `4//3`, результатом деления будет `1,3333`, ближайшее меньшее целое будет `1`, то при `-4//3` с результатом `-1,3333` таким числом будет `-2`, так как `-1 > -1,3333 > -2`

Comment: Получается, что не отбрасывает дробную часть, а округляет в меньшую сторону. Если бы отбрасывало дробную часть, то как раз было бы ожидаемо -1, а не -2. В случае округления в меньшую сторону - как раз ожидаемо, что получится -2. Это, на мой взгляд, не весьма математически верно, но так принято в Пайтоне, что ж, надо просто запомнить.

Answer (score 0):

Дополню ответ @cauf наглядной иллюстрацией, чуть расширив ваш код:

```
print(4//3, '<=', 4/3)
print(-4//3, '<=', -4/3) 

1 <= 1.3333333333333333
-2 <= -1.3333333333333333
```

Answer (score 0):

Целочисленное деление окргляет не в сторону 0, а в меньшую сторону. То есть для отрицательных значений модуль числа увеличивается, а для положительных - уменьшается. Если Вам нужно округление обычное, то используйте round(4/3)

```
round(4/3)=1
round(-4/3)=-1
```

У round() есть второй параметр - до скольки знаков округление:

```
round(4/3,1)=1.3
round(-4/3,5)=1.33333
```

Надеюсь я ответил на Ваш вопрос.